# Unable to make system-wide keyboard shortcut for X11's full-screen in Mac

Tags: mac-osx, x11

The keyboard shortcut for X11's full-screen mode is

```
Option-Command A
```

However, it works only if I click the X11 icon and then press the combination.

**How can you make a system-wide keyboard combination for the command on Mac OS X?**

Comment: Regardless of the X11-ness of the question, I'd like the answer to the 'system-wide keyboard combination'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems not to be a support for the feature by Mac at the moment.
The feature would apparently require to know better the internals of Macs.

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences -> Keyboard & Mouse

There is tab that allows you to confirm all keymappings both globally and within specific apps.

However, I'm on my PC at work so I can't be more specific, sorry. But, I do know you can do it there.

Comment: @Alex: The problem is that I need to know the name of the app which makes the full screen. I need to select it visually.